# Алгоритм удаления временных файлов

Tags: php

Постараюсь описать задачу. Имеется 1 скрипт, который генерирует файлы в папку `tmp/`.
После этого сразу же второй скрипт начинает отдавать файл клиенту (стартует загрузку на клиент) с поддержкой докачки (http_range), поэтому неизвестно, когда файл скачается.

После чего файл больше не нужен. Как организовать удаление файлов и по какому критерию? Пока только придумал удаление всех файлов во временной директории, время жизни которых дольше N минут.

P.S.: Я уже пытался выяснить, как определить, что файл скачался в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19395/%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-php-http_range).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Возможно, вариант отмороженный, но если через 10 мин можно открыть файл с помощью `fopen($file, 'a');` - значит, его не качают в данный момент.

Как вариант - сделать хэндлер для загрузки, в котором разбирать Accept-Range, и делать примерно так

```
fseek($f, $acceptRangeStart);
$flock = @fopen('__' . basename($fileToDownload) . $acceptRangeStart, 'w+');
@fclose($flock); // создаем лок-файл
echo fread($f, $acceptRangeBytes);
@unlink('__' . basename($fileToDownload) . $acceptRangeStart);
$finished = true;
foreach (scandir('tmp') as $fn) {
    if (strpos($fn, '__' . basename($fileToDownload)) !== false) {
        $finished = false; // если идет докачка, сбрасываем
        break;
    }
}
if ($finished) { // если лок-файлов не найдено
    unlink($fileToDownload); // удаляем основной файл
}
```

А чем вам, кстати, не нравится вариант, который используют почти все файлообменники? (*Ссылка для скачивания будет доступна в течение суток и только для этого компьютера*)

Comment: Идея с файлообменниками не приходила в голову, потому как ничего с них не качаю. Спс за нее. В ответе идея тоже неплохая, поэтому плюсую-вернее ставлю верный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант при генерации файла в его имя писать дату, время. Раз в день или раз в час (в зависимости от количества файлов в папке) по cron'у делать scandir() разбирать имя файлов и если дата меньше чем на N минут / часов / дней удалять его

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вот такой вариант тоже имеет место быть.

Смысл в общем в одной функции [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php) после завершения работы вызывается эта функция и удаляет файл который был прочитан.

В моей задаче, было важно, создать временный файл, прочитать файл и сразу после чтения удалить, собственно данный вариант с этим справляется.

Так же в место этого, можно использовать очереди задач.

```
/**
 * @param $name
 * @param $content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function temporaryFile($name, $content)
{
    $file = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
        trim(sys_get_temp_dir(), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).
        DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.
        ltrim($name, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    file_put_contents($file, $content);

    register_shutdown_function(
        function () use ($file) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    );

    return $file;
}
```